# select arbitrary amount of rows with N distinct values in foreign key referenced column

Tags: sqlite, sql

The database schema is

```
CREATE TABLE sites
(
    site_id           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    netloc            TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    last_visited      REAL DEFAULT 0,
    crawl_rate        REAL DEFAULT 2,
    crawl_frequency   REAL DEFAULT 604800,
    robots_txt        TEXT DEFAULT 0,
    robots_last_fetch REAL DEFAULT 0,
    allow_all         NUMERIC DEFAULT 0,
    disallow_all      NUMERIC DEFAULT 0,
    active            NUMERIC DEFAULT 0                           
 )

CREATE TABLE urls
(
     url_id       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     site_id      INTEGER REFERENCES sites (id) NOT NULL,
     scheme       TEXT NOT NULL,
     path         TEXT NOT NULL,
     last_visited REAL DEFAULT 0,
     UNIQUE( site_id, scheme, path)                                   
 )
```

As you can probably, guess, this is for a web crawler.

I want to get N of the sites that have crawlable urls associated with them and all of the 
aforementioned urls. A url is crawlable if `url.last_visited + site.crawl_frequency < current_time` where current_time comes from pythons `time.time()` function. What I'm looking for will probably begin with something like:

```
SELECT s.*, u.* FROM sites s, urls u ON s.site_id = u.site_id ...
```

Beyond that all I can think is that `GROUP BY` might have some role to play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a graceless query.  There's probably a more clever way to do this.

```
SELECT s.*, u.* 
FROM sites s, urls u ON s.site_id = u.site_id
WHERE s.site_id IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT site_id
     FROM urls uu INNER JOIN sites ss ON uu.site_id = ss.site_id
     WHERE uu.last_visited + ss.crawl_frequency < current_time 
     ORDER BY ss.site_id
     LIMIT n);
```

The subquery is supposed to return up to `n` distinct `site_id`s with least one crawlable URL.  The `ORDER BY` attribute needn't be `site_id`.  Actually `ORDER BY` isn't necessary at all. I just threw it in there because consistency is nice when playing with a new query.

The enclosing query returns all `url`s associated with `n` distinct `site`s, where each `site` has at least one crawlable `url`.  Note that not all `url`s returned are necessarily crawlable; the only guarantee is that at least one `url` per `site` is crawlable.  A returned `site` could have non-crawlable `url`s, too.

If only crawlable `url`s should be returned, the timing condition can be copied in the enclosing query.  I couldn't tell which behavior was required from the question.

P.S. I'm indulging in pedantry now, but the way `crawl_frequency` is used makes me think it could be called `crawl_period` or `crawl_delay` instead

Comment: Thanks, That's close enough to what I want to get the rest for myself. I'll edit my question later to give the full solution.